# Sails.js are sessions cleared from the store

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I looking around the documentation and can't seem to find this. I am using MongoDb as a session store for my application. I have set my session cookie to expire after 10 minutes via the following in the `session.js` file

```
cookie: {
   maxAge: 10 * 60 * 1000
}
```

When the cookie expires are the records deleted from the session store? or do i need to do it manually in mongo by setting an TTL on the collection? like:

```
sails.sessions.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 600 } )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation and testing it turns out that this works out of the box as default.Once you set the cookie max age in the sessions.js file like so:

```
cookie: {
   maxAge: 60 * 1000
}
```

in other words expire the session after 60 seconds. when sails creates the document to store in the collection sails places a property on the document called "expires" and sets it to the current date plus the cookie.maxAge.

and according to documentation found here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/ the process that comes to clean up the data runs about every 60 seconds so it could take at least that long on top of the max age to delete.

**Long story short** aslong as you set the maxAge the session will be deleted after that expiry time.